# Flashing a Cortex-M0+ device using an ISO file

Tags: arm, iso, flash-memory

I programmed a little code for motion detection device(DA14531 SmartBond TINY module based on a CortexM0+) and I am having some experiments with it. at the end and after debugging and testing, I generated an ISO file and now I want to flash the device. Is the process similar to burning the ISO file on a USB flash or is the process different? I only have one device and I dont want to do something irreversible so I came here for some guidance first.

I looked online for a while but nothing matches my specifique situation, so providing me with the correct links is also helpful

Comment: Could you please augment your question with the exact CPU and  operating system you are using ? What is exactly the memory device you want to flash your program into ? if you are using an of-the-shelf SBC, could you please augment your question with its brand/model ?

Comment: Do you want to use an ISO file because you think you need one, or because you know you need one ?

Comment: @Frant I want one, I know I can get there otherwise but I am curious to know how to do it with an ISO File!

Comment: @Frant DA14531 SmartBond TINY is the model I am using

Comment: is this a cortex-m or a cortex-a, makes a huge difference.  arm (linux based, cortex-a) does not boot like an x86, doesnt have a bios, etc.  Programming interfaces to the boot media are as a result different.  the processor core is not so relevant as the chip/board.  What chip and board are you using?

Comment: @BeNicePlz: Why exactly makes you think your situation is unique ?

Comment: @Frant so I am used to burning ISO files on a USB flash, but I guess the sitation is different here. When I looked on how to do it, I found tutorials on how to do for computers, android phones or  Iphones... so devices with screens. but mine doesn't have a screen.

Comment: @old_timer it's a ARM Cortex M0+

Comment: @BeNicePlz: your burn ISO images on a USB key when your target system does support booting from a USB key. This is not the case of your target system I think.

Comment: There is mention of it I guess in the  DA14531 SmartBond TINY manual, but I may have missed it, Can you provide a link the the documentation describing the 'boot key' you are referencing ?

Comment: @ the DADA14531 SmartBond TINY itself doesn't but the stup has a boot / reset key

Comment: Having a reset/boot push-button is not the same than having a USB connector for being able to boot form a USB key.

Comment: ok please pay attention to the terms. If you're asking about a booting key then no! if you ask about a USB connector then yes I have it

Comment: I think you are the one not paying attention: I mentioned 'support booting from a USB key' and never a 'booting key'.

Comment: An iso with a cortex-m makes no sense, how would one even attempt to do that, one thing has nothing to do with another.  Like trying to use a suitcase to fill your car with gas.

Comment: It doesnt make too much sense for a cortex-a either.  but read the documentation for the part (part first, which is not from arm, then if the part says swd thats where you refer to arm).  Then for the board.  Nucleo boards for example you plug the usb in and copy the binary file (NOT an iso or anything that remotely resenbles an iso, rarely can you use a container type file format, certainly not with the nucleos or other similar boards from other similar vendors).   Other interfaces are uart and spi.

Comment: there is a remote possibility that on a cortex-m7 with lots of resources you can have enough of an operating system and file system, etc to possibly read an ISO image on a usb media and then maybe read, parse, and run programs there.   cortex-m0+ cant see how or why you would try, what interface do you have on your chip (remember not arm, the chip vendor) that you could interface to a media that could hold an ISO?

Comment: I dont see that module having anything really useful for interfacing with media that holds an ISO.

Comment: ISO is generally for pcs with an x86 and a BIOS,  this is not a PC nor does it remotely resemble it.

Comment: Irreversible has to do with the chip itself, its protection, and the board and its programming interfaces and chip specific features brought out or not on the board.  some chips are brickable.  And some chips that are not brickable may not be unbricked due to board limitations.

Answer (score 1):

The ISO 9660 format was designed for optical disks, using it is likely irrelevant to your use case, since there is IMHO a near to zero chance you will find a tool that will allow you to flash directly your program in a Cortex-M0+ device from a file in ISO 9660 format.

And if you may flash the ISO file as is in your Cortex-M0+ flash memory, your device will likely be unable to boot since it does rely on very specific information (stack pointer, first instruction to be executed) to be flashed in a verify specific location, not mentioning the waste of flash memory space this would cause.

That is, if Dialog documentation does not specifically mention the possibility of flashing a file in ISO 9660 format, this is likely (and not surprising) that this is not possible using Dialog software and hardware support tools.

Comment: please make your answer precise !! you just got me more confused

Comment: What exactly is confusing you in it?

Comment: You say I cant burn the ISO then you tell me I need a bunch of tools to do it! is it possible and assuming I have the tools how do I do it?

Comment: I say you can flash it provided you have a JTAG/SWD probe or you can if you can use the serial port and some Dialog-provided software for doing so. And yes, I assume that you have the tools or at least have read the documentation on how to flash the device you bought before asking if you can flash an ISO file.

Comment: Sir! I have developped, deugged and tested this code using the software provided by dialog. the software can let u program through serial, I can get the software through serial port but this is  NOT my question. I am interested in the case of an ISO file and Dialog says nothing about it.

Comment: Dialog documentation says nothing about it precisely because, as I said, using a file  in ISO 9660 format is irrelevant in your use case. I you are not ready to face this truth, I cannot help further. I would also suggest you to improve your attitude when asking questions on this forum if you want to get help: you are the one using vague terms such as 'booting key', confusing a USB key with a reset/boot push-button, but you are the one complaining about the lack of precision.

Comment: what attitude? so asking for explanation and clarification is now bad? also what truth I dont want to face? and how is this related to my question? that's one side, the second one, think of this example: I want to give the "CODE" to someone who has the hardware to install on it. An ISO/executable option would be more practical than to tell them get the software and jsagger and the cables and then program it No? so my question is valid and I don't know if the option exists but you seem like you don't either. I still don't see this" truth" hoestly. Hopefully we can get some insight from someone,

Comment: If you do not see, as I said, I cannot help further. My answer is still valid still. And good luck for getting some insight from someone (I mean, a different one...).

Comment: An iso is gross overkill to provide a file to another person.  Simply provide the binary file.  If I want to distribute even software for a PC, an ISO would be by far the last way to do this unless it was a very large installation.  The binary itself.  The binary in a zip or tarball, or an installer binary if the number of files required is complicated or system specfic.  In this case it is a small chunk of bytes, a single chunk of bytes that goes into the flash.

Comment: Worst case the loadable image (a few kbytes) and a file format around it to indicate the address.  The tools you use to write the flash on the part dictate what the file format is, that is how it works.  If they dictate an intel hex file then you have to use an intel hex file.  Motorola s-record, then you have to do that.  Elf file format, you have to do that or raw binary image you have to do that.  Those are the primary options there are few file formats beyond that you will find in the wild and these days elf and a raw binary are the main to ihex and srec are old fashioned.

Comment: It would be gross overkill to create an ISO for a pc with the single few kbyte file forcing then end user to then have to burn that ISO somewhere on a usb stick or optical media or perhaps finding more software to attempt to read an ISO without burning it somewhere.  Not to mention the distribution is not significantly larger than the data it contains.

Answer (score 1):

So when you read the documentation for this product you noticed there is an SWD interface which is certainly one way into the part.  When you further examined the pro kit and other solutions from them you see they mention segger jlink interfaces for debugging etc.  Further reinforcing SWD as at least one interface into the part.  Through that interface (SWD is ARM) you access the flash controller (has nothing whatsoever to do with arm it is chip specific) and through that you write your application binary that the part will run (the machine code and data that the processor uses, your application).

ISO is closely related to PC's with a BIOS/EFI which also means x86, and has nothing whatsoever to do with a microcontroller much less a non x86, non BIOS/EFI PC/Laptop.  It is extremely unlikely that you can get enough software on a cortex-m0(+) based platform that if you had an interface to media that can hold it that you could parse it and extract anything useful, and then have resources left to load and execute any programs in ram.  No way whatsoever in any part I have heard of that you could do this in ram such that you could extract something you could load to the flash on the part.  Plus you have to get that program into the part before you can then later support ISO, if you could, which you can't.

The only remote way an ISO makes any sense at all or has any context is if on your PC you boot off of an ISO image and that ISO image for the PC (not the mcu) contains a development system.  For example a pre-prepared Linux operating system distro with the tools from the vendor for this part so that you don't have to install the development system on your computer you can run it off a ramdisk using a live image on an ISO. That development system would not use ISO files but the proper file formats to develop binaries and load them to the board via SWD or some other chip/board specific interface.

Beyond that there is no further reason to talk about ISO's and microcontrollers.

Some chip vendors (not arm, the chip vendor) may also provide a factory bootloader or logic that supports for example a uart, maybe spi, maybe i2c, maybe usb interface that you can use chip (not arm) specific software to talk to software running on that chip (the bootloader) that can then write to the flash.  You can also write your own bootloader if there are enough resources in the system.  The (arm based) mcu world is moving away from these bootloaders, two of the three main companies that used to always have them have started to remove them or disable them as a default feature.

Other companies provide no other interface than SWD to program the part, SWD or nothing.  Certainly in the cortex-m0+ market where every penny counts and the extra flash for a bootloader and extra chip real estate, etc add to the overall cost for a legacy feature that is becoming less important because developers can now easily obtain SWD interface modules for a few dollars.  It is not like the old days where a JTAG board cost $2000.  At this time all cortex-m parts support SWD, making it the most useful interface and reminding developers that having tools that can access that interface being worth the ($5, plus time to learn to use it) investment.

The tools used to write the flash dictate what file formats are supported, these days a raw binary image or an elf file format are the main two.  The old days included file formats like Intel hex and Motorola s-record but it is only old timers like me that favor those file formats, even though an elf is trivial to parse, and a raw binary image even simpler, about four lines of code.

Some chip vendors do not provide enough information to roll your own, but most often they do.  Arm long ago released the SWD interface information, so it is technically possible to roll your own and then support whatever file format you want.  But you would have to distribute this tool along with the ISO file, so you would what use a second ISO file to distribute the tools to read the first one.  Based on your question and comments you are a long long way from writing tools like these.  Especially when working tools like openocd exist that support the main file formats (elf and raw binary) and can speak SWD into the current line of cortex-m cores.

Again if you are suggesting using an ISO to distribute tools along with your binary to be loaded and run on a PC that might make sense, but it is easier for the end user to simply download the tools from the chip vendor or tools vendor and then download the binary file from you, rather than put in the extra work to deal with an ISO.